# Remove custom link in teaser

Tags: navigation, datetime, nodes

In drupal 7 I created new content type and also created new view to display nodes of this content type. After playing a bit with Calendar module I managed somehow to put link to calendar to node teaser links. Now I can see "*Read more*" link inline with "*Calendar*" link. It's pointing to calendar view which no longer exists.

Could you please advise me how to get rid of this "*Calenar*" link in teaser links? When I uncheck "Display links" in view settings (`Edit View -> Format -> Show -> Content | Teaser`), it disappears together with "*Read more*" link. But I'd like to have "*Read more*" link without "*Calendar*" link.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the Display links and add the below line in your `node.tpl.php` present under your themes folder `sites/all/themes/yourtheme`

```
<a href='<?php print $node_url; ?>'>read more..</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you unchecked the `Display links` from the view, then you can display the `read more` link in your `node` template file.

You need to create `node` template for your content type like `node--[contenttype].tpl.php` where `contenttype` is your content type, in your theme directory and clear the cache.

You can add below code in `node` template for your content type to display links `read more` only in teaser view.

```
if ($teaser) {

 print render($content['links']['node']);
}
```

There is another method for the same.

You can select `content` as `format` in your view and can add `title`, `Content: Link` fields in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys, for your suggestions.

When my problem appeared, I didn't modify any tpl files, so I felt this has to be solved in some other way. When I removed this content type and view and recreated them again, calendar link was still there.

So I removed it again and created a dump of my DB. I was fulltext searching for that content type name and I found it.

In table `variable` there was variable with name `calendar_date_link_<my content type name>`. I removed it and calendar link disappeared. I hope this hasn't broken anything else.